# iOS app crashing in apple app review but completely unreproducible locally

Tags: ios, xamarin

we have recently developed a Xamarin forms app which is built for both Android and iOS. The Android version is on the google play store and is working as expected. The iOS version works on all of our devices and emulators but is crashing when apple test it during their app review process using iOS 9.3.3. We have symbolicated the crash report but are at a loss as to what is possibly causing the crash.

The symbolicated crash report is below and would greatly appreciate any assistance people can provide that will help us track down the cause of the crash.

> Incident Identifier: 1D827CDB-F42D-457B-AE32-F887824E7EFE
>   CrashReporter Key:   ed6d5c5e7f0dc0721d5e88ce52e57230f0fb842f Hardware
>   Model:      xxx Process:             SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS [1615]
>   Path:
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DB6ED5ED-7A9A-4809-A92F-514EC1BC35C9/SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS.app/SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS Identifier:          com.swiftpos.loyalty Version:             4
>   (6.48.4) Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native) Parent Process:
>   launchd [1]
>
> Date/Time:           2016-07-25 17:31:45.45 -0700 Launch Time:
>   2016-07-25 17:31:43.43 -0700 OS Version:          iOS 9.3.3 (13G34)
>   Report Version:      105
>
> Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT) Exception Subtype:
>   KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000 Triggered by Thread:  0
>
> Filtered syslog: None found
>
> Last Exception Backtrace: 0   CoreFoundation
>     0x182ce2db0 0x182bb8000 + 1224112 1   libobjc.A.dylib
>     0x182347f80 0x182340000 + 32640 2   CoreFoundation
>     0x182ce2a70 0x182bb8000 + 1223280 3   SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS
>     0x100f6f078 WriteZStream + 13814828 4   SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS
>     0x100f5f62c WriteZStream + 13750752 5   SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS
>     0x100f5f46c WriteZStream + 13750304 6   SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS
>     0x100f612e8 WriteZStream + 13758108 7   SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS
>     0x1004f9e84 WriteZStream + 2849336 8   SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS
>     0x10016bfbc plcrash::BIT::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator::next(unsigned int*,
>   plcrash::BIT::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long
>   long*) + 252664 9   SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS           0x1001c2ae4
>   plcrash::BIT::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator::next(unsigned int*,
>   plcrash::BIT::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long
>   long*) + 607776 10  SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS           0x1001c766c
>   plcrash::BIT::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator::next(unsigned int*,
>   plcrash::BIT::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long
>   long*) + 627112 11  SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS           0x1001c7264
>   plcrash::BIT::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator::next(unsigned int*,
>   plcrash::BIT::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long
>   long*) + 626080 12  SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS           0x10015f214
>   plcrash::BIT::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator::next(unsigned int*,
>   plcrash::BIT::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long
>   long*) + 200016 13  SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS           0x10015e8fc
>   plcrash::BIT::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator::next(unsigned int*,
>   plcrash::BIT::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long
>   long*) + 197688 14  SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS           0x100157a54
>   plcrash::BIT::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator::next(unsigned int*,
>   plcrash::BIT::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long
>   long*) + 169360 15  SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS           0x10052f388
>   WriteZStream + 3067708 16  SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS        0x100358aac
>   WriteZStream + 1140320 17  SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS        0x1003574b0
>   WriteZStream + 1134692 18  SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS        0x10094e3e8
>   WriteZStream + 7389084 19  SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS        0x10098b944
>   WriteZStream + 7640312 20  SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS        0x1004f9e84
>   WriteZStream + 2849336 21  SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS        0x10016bfbc
>   plcrash::BIT::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator::next(unsigned int*,
>   plcrash::BIT::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long
>   long*) + 252664 22  SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS           0x1001c2ae4
>   plcrash::BIT::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator::next(unsigned int*,
>   plcrash::BIT::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long
>   long*) + 607776 23  SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS           0x100f744cc
>   WriteZStream + 13836416 24  SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS           0x100f74fc8
>   WriteZStream + 13839228 25  Foundation                        0x1836b802c
>   0x1835c4000 + 999468 26  CoreFoundation                   0x182c9909c
>   0x182bb8000 + 921756 27  CoreFoundation                   0x182c98b30
>   0x182bb8000 + 920368 28  CoreFoundation                   0x182c96830
>   0x182bb8000 + 911408 29  CoreFoundation                   0x182bc0c50
>   0x182bb8000 + 35920 30  GraphicsServices                  0x1844a8088
>   0x18449c000 + 49288 31  UIKit                             0x187ea2088
>   0x187e24000 + 516232 32  SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS          0x1009d0b64
>   WriteZStream + 7923480 33  SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS        0x10093cb3c
>   WriteZStream + 7317232 34  SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS        0x10093cafc
>   WriteZStream + 7317168 35  SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS        0x1002436c4
>   WriteZStream + 4728 36  SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS           0x1004f9e84
>   WriteZStream + 2849336 37  SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS        0x10016bfbc
>   plcrash::BIT::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator::next(unsigned int*,
>   plcrash::BIT::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long
>   long*) + 252664 38  SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS           0x1001c2ae4
>   plcrash::BIT::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator::next(unsigned int*,
>   plcrash::BIT::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long
>   long*) + 607776 39  SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS           0x1001c6f34
>   plcrash::BIT::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator::next(unsigned int*,
>   plcrash::BIT::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long
>   long*) + 625264 40  SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS           0x100241ed0
>   xamarin_GetFolderPath + 1960 41  SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS
>     0x100f90f38 WriteZStream + 13953772 42  libdyld.dylib
>     0x18275e8b8 0x18275c000 + 10424
>
> Global Trace Buffer (reverse chronological seconds):
>   6148914687.764939 CFNetwork                   0x00000001832c58e0 TCP Conn 0x12e7b2840 SSL Handshake DONE
>   6148914687.955328 CFNetwork                   0x00000001832c57f0 TCP Conn 0x12e7b2840 starting SSL negotiation
>   6148914687.955688 CFNetwork                   0x0000000183367e7c TCP Conn 0x12e7b2840 complete. fd: 5, err: 0
>   6148914687.956469 CFNetwork                   0x00000001833693a8 TCP Conn 0x12e7b2840 event 1. err: 0
>   6148914688.040974 CFNetwork                   0x0000000183369480 TCP Conn 0x12e7b2840 started
>   6148914688.043079 CFNetwork                   0x00000001833c3e5c Creating default cookie storage with default identifier
>   6148914688.043079 CFNetwork                   0x00000001833c3e28 Faulting in CFHTTPCookieStorage singleton
>   6148914688.043085 CFNetwork                   0x0000000183415e50 Faulting in NSHTTPCookieStorage singleton
>
> Thread 0 name:  tid_c07  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread Thread
>   0 Crashed: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x000000018287c11c
>   0x182860000 + 114972 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x0000000182948ef8 0x182944000 + 20216 2   libsystem_c.dylib
>     0x00000001827eddc8 0x18278c000 + 400840 3   SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS
>     0x000000010011c320 0x1000b4000 + 426784 4   CoreFoundation
>     0x0000000182ce3138 0x182bb8000 + 1225016 5   libobjc.A.dylib
>     0x000000018234823c 0x182340000 + 33340 6   SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS
>     0x000000010010a290 0x1000b4000 + 352912 7   libc++abi.dylib
>     0x000000018233af44 0x182320000 + 110404 8   libc++abi.dylib
>     0x000000018233a85c 0x182320000 + 108636 9   libobjc.A.dylib
>     0x0000000182348094 0x182340000 + 32916 10  CoreFoundation
>     0x0000000182ce2a70 0x182bb8000 + 1223280 11  SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS 
>     0x0000000100f6f078 WriteZStream + 13814828 12 
>   SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS           0x0000000100f5f62c WriteZStream +
>   13750752 13  SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS          0x0000000100f5f46c
>   WriteZStream + 13750304 14  SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS
>     0x0000000100f612e8 WriteZStream + 13758108 15 
>   SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS           0x00000001004f9e84 WriteZStream +
>   2849336 16  SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS           0x000000010016bfbc
>   plcrash::BIT::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator::next(unsigned int*,
>   plcrash::BIT::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long
>   long*) + 252664 17  SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS           0x00000001001c2ae4
>   plcrash::BIT::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator::next(unsigned int*,
>   plcrash::BIT::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long
>   long*) + 607776 18  SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS           0x00000001001c766c
>   plcrash::BIT::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator::next(unsigned int*,
>   plcrash::BIT::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long
>   long*) + 627112 19  SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS           0x00000001001c7264
>   plcrash::BIT::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator::next(unsigned int*,
>   plcrash::BIT::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long
>   long*) + 626080 20  SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS           0x000000010015f214
>   plcrash::BIT::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator::next(unsigned int*,
>   plcrash::BIT::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long
>   long*) + 200016 21  SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS           0x000000010015e8fc
>   plcrash::BIT::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator::next(unsigned int*,
>   plcrash::BIT::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long
>   long*) + 197688 22  SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS           0x0000000100157a54
>   plcrash::BIT::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator::next(unsigned int*,
>   plcrash::BIT::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long
>   long*) + 169360 23  SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS           0x000000010052f388
>   WriteZStream + 3067708 24  SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS
>     0x0000000100358aac WriteZStream + 1140320 25  SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS
>     0x00000001003574b0 WriteZStream + 1134692 26  SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS
>     0x000000010094e3e8 WriteZStream + 7389084 27  SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS
>     0x000000010098b944 WriteZStream + 7640312 28  SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS
>     0x00000001004f9e84 WriteZStream + 2849336 29  SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS
>     0x000000010016bfbc
>   plcrash::BIT::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator::next(unsigned int*,
>   plcrash::BIT::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long
>   long*) + 252664 30  SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS           0x00000001001c2ae4
>   plcrash::BIT::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator::next(unsigned int*,
>   plcrash::BIT::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long
>   long*) + 607776 31  SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS           0x0000000100f744cc
>   WriteZStream + 13836416 32  SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS
>     0x0000000100f74fc8 WriteZStream + 13839228 33  Foundation
>     0x00000001836b802c 0x1835c4000 + 999468 34  CoreFoundation
>     0x0000000182c9909c 0x182bb8000 + 921756 35  CoreFoundation
>     0x0000000182c98b30 0x182bb8000 + 920368 36  CoreFoundation
>     0x0000000182c96830 0x182bb8000 + 911408 37  CoreFoundation
>     0x0000000182bc0c50 0x182bb8000 + 35920 38  GraphicsServices
>     0x00000001844a8088 0x18449c000 + 49288 39  UIKit
>     0x0000000187ea2088 0x187e24000 + 516232 40  SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS
>     0x00000001009d0b64 WriteZStream + 7923480 41  SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS
>     0x000000010093cb3c WriteZStream + 7317232 42  SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS
>     0x000000010093cafc WriteZStream + 7317168 43  SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS
>     0x00000001002436c4 WriteZStream + 4728 44  SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS
>     0x00000001004f9e84 WriteZStream + 2849336 45  SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS
>     0x000000010016bfbc
>   plcrash::BIT::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator::next(unsigned int*,
>   plcrash::BIT::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long
>   long*) + 252664 46  SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS           0x00000001001c2ae4
>   plcrash::BIT::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator::next(unsigned int*,
>   plcrash::BIT::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long
>   long*) + 607776 47  SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS           0x00000001001c6f34
>   plcrash::BIT::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator::next(unsigned int*,
>   plcrash::BIT::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long
>   long*) + 625264 48  SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS           0x0000000100241ed0
>   xamarin_GetFolderPath + 1960 49  SwiftPOSMemberPortaliOS
>     0x0000000100f90f38 WriteZStream + 13953772 50  libdyld.dylib
>     0x000000018275e8b8 0x18275c000 + 10424

Comment: `Exception Type: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT) Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000 Triggered by Thread: 0` - You're dereferencing `null` at some point. Other than that I unfortunately don't know anything else

Comment: It looks like a bunch of "your" code doesn't have debug symbols - I assume that's because it's actually Xamarin code. You could try symbolicating against the debug version of the Xamarin library, so you can find out what part of WriteZStream you're in when you're crashing.

Comment: I think you are correct @Jeeter it might be because the object is null. I actually just spoke to an apple support member and got them to send through the HockeyApp crash log which is much more usefull than the above log.

if (response.Data != null)
            {
                IEnumerable<Setting> settings = response.Data.Settings;
                    if (settings.Any(s => string.Equals(s.Name, "Title" ... etc

There are multiple calls like this to retrieve the settings, but we don't actually check for "If response.Data.Settings != null".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thankyou to all who answered. We have found the problem.

Our api session key was the issue. We where not converting the session key expiration time into universal time, so that after deserializing the empty json response, it created a new instance of the type of data and the value was null.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert at iOS stack traces, but these are the parts of it which I consider might be useful clues:

- xamarin_GetFolderPath
- Faulting in NSHTTPCookieStorage singleton

It might be worth asking Apple what sequence of actions they performed before the error occurred. It could be that they are testing a code path which you haven't tested. Also, iOS 9.3.3 has only been out for a few days, are you sure that you have tested on this version?